# The distribution of collision stopping time in 2D random walk

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Assume two particles A at $(0, 0)$ and B at $(a, b)$ in 2D discrete grid, both of them have the same possibility of $\frac{1}{4}$ for moving up/down/left/right (i.e. 2D random walk). We define the stopping time $T_c$ as they have a collision (reaching the same point). How can we get the distribution of the stopping time $T_c$?

Comment: One can assume $a$ and $b$ has the same parity, and focus on the vector $\Delta=A-B$. The motion of $\Delta$ can be described as $\Delta_{t+1}=\Delta_t+\delta_1(1,1)+\delta_2(1,-1)$, where $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are i.i.d. variables with $P(\delta_1=1)=P(\delta_1=-1)=1/4$ and $P(\delta_1=0)=1/2$.

Comment: This may take a full-blown paper. Cf. e.g. the much, much simpler problem treated in Lemma 2.3 in the paper at https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~jfrichey/pagedocs/rw_collisions.pdf

Comment: @LeechLattice, could you add details to your comment? Assuming parity only reduces the dimension of the problem, but we still need to find the stopping time of $\Delta$. I understand here that we look for the first $t$ such that $\Delta_t=0$. Which is what the OP asked in the first place.