# The distribution of hitting time in 2D-lattice random walk

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Assume a particle at $(0,0)$ with the same possibility of $1/4$ for moving up/down/left/right (i.e. random walk in 2D lattice). We define the stopping time  as it hits $(a,b)$. How can we get the distribution of the stopping time ?

Comment: What is $(a, b)$ as a subset of 2-D lattice?

Comment: Surely $(a,b)$ is the point with coordinates $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Is this equivalent to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411878/the-distribution-of-collision-stopping-time-in-2d-random-walk , using LeechLattice's comment there?

Comment: Yes, $(a, b)$ is the coordinate of the point to hit.

Comment: Actually, it's equivalent (both of the problems are posted by me).

Comment: So please don’t ask the same question twice. It’s rude!

Comment: Sorry, I just think the form of this problem is much simpler and would attract more answers.

Comment: @JamesMartin: Of course! Sorry, somehow I could not stop thinking $(a,b)$ stood for an interval or something.